# Comparing protocol upgrades in Cardano vs Ethereum

Tags: stake-pool

I’ve read some of the available Hard Fork combinator press release info [like the IOHK release blogpost](https://iohk.io/en/blog/posts/2020/05/07/combinator-makes-easy-work-of-shelley-hard-fork/) but as a blockchain newb, I don’t have a good grasp of how this substantially improves upon the stakepool operator experience when compared with other L1 Blockchains like Ethereum.

Can anyone unpack what a protocol upgrade currently looks like for an Ethereum miner (or any other comparable L1 blockchain)?